# Display appearing as 2 screens

Tags: windows-10, display-settings, laptop-display

When I look at the display properties, my main laptop monitor is being assigned 2 numbers.
[image]

Because this was a new one on me and I did not notice it. I also had an external monitor connected. I wanted to extend rather than duplicate and did that.

After doing that, it seems that my laptop monitor was also extended as if it were 2 screens. But obviously only one part appears. And all my main windows are in the "hidden" screen so I cannot access them. That includes the "display properties" dialog that appears in the hidden part, so I cannot undo the change.

When I unplug the external monitor, I can access the windows because it is not set as extended in this configuration. As soon as I re-plug it, it goes back to the save extended view, so I could not undo it. Not that it would matter because there is no much point if I can only use it as duplicated screens.

It means I can no longer work with an external monitor. As long as I have this "2 numbers for my laptop monitor", if I try to extend, some of my desktop will be in this virtual extension that I don't know how to access.

Note that when doing the screen shot, there was no external monitor plugged in (so not in extended mode). However it is still showing an external screen, in addition to the 2 numbers for my laptop monitor. This is quite messed up.

Any one has an idea how to correct that? I have tried but could not think of a query that was pointing me to why a single monitor would have 2 numbers assigned to it.

Comment: My idea is that you laptop has "extension" between screens 1 and 2 and "screen mirror" between screens 1 and 3. Right click on desktop -> screens ->  multiple screens and set the proper combination you want

Comment: I don't have a screen 3. I don't even have a second monitor plugged at the moment. Only my laptop and nothing else. It still shows with 2 numbers.

I don't know how separately configure such as 2 screens being mirrored while another is extended. I can only see all are duplicated or all are extended.

Finally, if I DO plugin my external monitor, I am back is this limbo where I cannot even access the "display properties" dialog. It exists and its content shows in the preview if my mouse is over it on the taskbar, but its location is in this "virtual" screen so I cannot interact.